# If a Javascript object has a property which holds a reference to a function, can I get that property name from within the function itself?

Tags: javascript

So:

```js
var obj = {
  'key': function() {
    // get 'key' here
  }
};
obj.key();
```

Example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tsUz6WY1qIvuoie3qSUv?p=preview

```js
var logger = {
  'warn': function(msg) {
    var logLvl = 'warn'; // <-- want to get the string 'warn' right here

    console.log('[', logLvl, ']', msg);
  }
};
logger.warn('Computer is exploding.'); // => [ warn ] Computer is exploding.
```

I can only think of the convoluted method of using a named function and searching `this` by the value of the function:

http://plnkr.co/edit/IHu087timHZCA2EbjDUa?p=preview

```js
var logger = {
  'warn': function func(msg) {
    console.log('[', _.invert(this)[func], ']', msg);
  }
};
logger.warn('Computer is exploding.');
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

---

UPDATE: So here's more detail on why I'm asking.

This is an Angular application. Here's list of presets. A preset has a name and two numbers:
https://github.com/Wideshanks/breatherBar/blob/rmUI/app.js#L372

These get rendered as list items on the front end:
https://github.com/Wideshanks/breatherBar/blob/rmUI/index.html#L42

When someone clicks on the list item, I want to add a new default pattern to the list and set the name/two numbers to what's in the preset.

The presets are functions which add new patterns. The two numbers are defined inside the function body, but the name of the preset is outside the function: it's the property name in $scope.presets:
https://github.com/Wideshanks/breatherBar/blob/rmUI/app.js#L359

Probably just need to rethink the whole thing, because the way I did it has ended up convoluted.

Comment: The answer is no, at least no way that's not a complete hack. There's no intrinsic relationship between an object property whose value is a reference to a function, and the function itself. It's just a property and a value. What are you trying to accomplish? There may be an idiomatic way to do it in JavaScript.

Comment: Added the real world application which caused the question, but I think the problem is probably that: not finding an idiomatic way to do what I'm doing.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you're up against. Personally, this is the kind of situation where I'd look for a way to build functions with closures dynamically. That is, instead of thinking about your data structure as a thing that's just statically declared as an object literal, think of it as something you construct with code. My answer below is a (tiny) example of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rig up something like this:

```
var logLevels = [ "trace", "debug", "info", "warn", "error" ];

var logger = logLevels.reduce(function(logger, level) {
  logger[level] = function(msg) {
    console.log("[" + level + "] " + msg);
  };
  return logger;
}, {});
```

That iterates through the list of (made-up of course) log levels, adding a function for each. The function relies on the closure created around the `.reduce()` callback. Each function behaves according to the `logger` property with which it's associated, but it's not *intrinsically* bound up that way.